# JAXB marshalling omitting prefix

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb

I have a JAXB co0nfiguration for marshalling a Java Object to XML. It does the job, however, it omits the namespace prefix and append `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?` infront of the marshalled string.

```
    <beans:bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"  p:contextPath="org.ncpdp.schema.script">
         <beans:property name="schema" value="classpath:/schema/SCRIPT_XML_10_6_OPPR.xsd"/>
         <beans:property name="marshallerProperties">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="jaxb.formatted.output"><beans:value type="boolean">true</beans:value></beans:entry>
                 <beans:entry key="com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper" value-ref="namespaceMapper"></beans:entry>

            </beans:map>
         </beans:proper

ty>
    </beans:bean>
```

```
</beans:bean>

public class NamespaceMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper implements ListenerConstants{

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion,
            boolean requirePrefix) {
         if(NAME_SPACE_SCHEMA_URL.equals(namespaceUri)) {
                return NS_PREFIX_SCR;
            } else if(KPRX_NAME_SPACE_URL.equals(namespaceUri)) {
                return NS_PREFIX_V5;
            }
            return suggestion;
    }

}

 public String marshal(final Object object) throws JAXBException {
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class );
        final Marshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        unmarshaller.marshal(object, new StreamResult(writer));

        return writer.toString();
    }
```

I want a message with a prefix something like

```
<NS2:TEST>
<NS2:ID>123</NS2:ID>
</NS2:TEST>
```

and without this declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify your header with the following:

```
unmarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "");
unmarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

The namespace mapping likely isn't happening because you don't tell your marshaller about your new implementation.

Before you marshal, set the namespace prefix property to your new class object.

```
unmarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespaceMapper());
```

You may have to remove the `final` modifier in order to modify the object, but I'm not 100%

BTW, it's a little confusing that you call your marshaller `unmarshaller`, but it's your code...